# Exibir dado no textView

Tags: android

Tenho um banco de dados em uma aplicação do `android`, gostaria que o nome campo que há na tabela, preenchesse o `text` do `TextView`. Vi alguns exemplos mas não consegui implementar, o  `getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(sqlNome, null);` sempre fica em vermelho, ou seja, não consigo utilizá-lo. É somente um dado que estará na tabela.

**Segue o código que tentei implementar:**

```
criaBanco = new CriaBanco(getBaseContext());
sqlNome = "select nome from tabela";
Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(sqlNome, null);

textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
if (!criaBanco.NOME.isEmpty()) {
    textView.setText(sqlNome);
}
else {
    textView.setText("NOME");
}

cursor.close();
```

Comment: Não será `Cursor cursor = criaBanco.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(sqlNome, null);`?

Comment: @ramaral vc está correto. obrigado. Coloque como resposta para que possa marcá-la e colocar 1 voto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getReadableDatabase()` é um método da classe [SQLiteOpenHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html).

Suponho que a classe *CriaBanco* herde dela, assim, pode aceder a esse método e executar a *query*, desta forma:

```
Cursor cursor = criaBanco.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(sqlNome, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia Henrique,
O método `getReadableDatabase()` deve ser executado no seu banco de dados.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = criaBanco.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sqlNome,null);
 if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                       cursor.moveToFirst();
                       String txt = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(nomeColuna));

                   }
```

Isso deve te retornar a String e então é só usar o `textView.setText(txt);`

O código acima retorna somente o primeiro resultado, seu select parece permitir o retorno de todos os dados, se quiser retornar vários registros, após o `cursor.moveToFirst()` faça um do while com a condição `moveToNext()`

```
do{

}while(cursor .moveToNext());
```

Comment: Obrigado! Neste caso realmente só tem um resultado. Somente há a inserção de 1 dado, o restante é somente update.